Custom UserControls + MVVM - WPF - Sending written value back to parent
I created some DependencProperties for my custom UserControl. The "Read-Values" get inherited from the parent, but if I write anything into my TextBox, it won't get "send" back to my parent UserControl.
Prior question: Custom UserControls + MVVM - WPF / Prism-Framework
So, basically I have a custom UserControl, that I want to use within other UserControls to reduce duplicate xaml code:
...
        <TextBox BorderBrush="{Binding PropertyFG, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                         Foreground="{Binding PropertyFG, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                         md:HintAssist.HelperText="{Binding PropertyHT, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                         md:TextFieldAssist.LeadingIcon="HumanGreetingVariant"
                         Style="{StaticResource ParamTextBox}"
                         Text="{Binding PropertyInput, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
...

Everything, besides the PropertyInput Property works as expected.
I created each DependencyProperty like this within the Code-Behind:
...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyInputProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(PropertyInput),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(TxtInput));

        public string PropertyInput
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(PropertyInputProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PropertyInputProperty, value); }
        }
...

Within another, UserControl, I use this custom control like this - using the values from the corresponding View-Model. PropertyName and PropertyMargin is from another component inside the Custom UserControl that I did not include here.
...
            <uc:TxtInput PropertyName="Developer Name" 
                         PropertyMargin="{Binding NameMargin}" 
                         PropertyFG="{Binding NameFG}" 
                         PropertyHT="{Binding NameHT}"
                         PropertyInput="{Binding Name}"/>
...

ViewModel:
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set 
            { 
                SetProperty(ref _name, value);
                _newProgrammer.Name = value;
                ValidateUserInput();
            }
        }

So, basically, if the value changes within the PropertyInput (so, I update the Textbox by writing sth in it) - a specific method of the ViewModel shall be invoked - as you can see above. Unfortunately, it seems like the value from the custom UserControl does not get sent back to the UserControl where I am using it.
Any tip is helpful, thx!

The custom property binding must be TwoWay. See Data Binding Overview.
